# Agrupar por el valor más repetido en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día a todos, ojalá pudieran por favor ayudarme a resolver la siguiente consulta:

Tengo dos columnas en SQL (Cliente y sucursal)

```
Cliente Sucursal
1   La Joya
1   La Joya
1   Nevado
2   Penjamo
2   Penjamo
2   Nevado
```

Quiero agrupar por cliente, la sucursal más repetida para cada cliente; es decir, busco algo como lo siguiente:

```
Cliente Sucursal
1   La Joya
2   Penjamo
```

He intentado de varias maneras, pero no logro agruparlo.

Comment: Hola @TOMZG, por favor modifica tu pregunta agregando el código que has intentado para poder ayudarte un poco mejor en tu consulta.

Comment: Qué pasa si tienes sucursales que aparecen la misma cantidad de veces para un cliente?

Comment: Muchas gracias, agrego el código.  
;With cpd as(
Select cpd.Cliente, cpd.Sucursal, cpd.Prestamo,
 Rank()Over (Partition by Cliente order by Prestamo desc) as Rango
From dbo.Segmentacion           cpd
--Order by Cliente Desc
)
 Select

Comment: Tienes razón @Lamak, el problema que se está presentando es que el cliente puede tener el mismo número de visitas en diferentes sucursales, el número 1 (en rango) aparecerá varias veces. ¿Tienen alguna idea como seleccionar cualquiera de los 1 que aparezcan, indistintamente cuando ese sea el caso?

Comment: @TOMZG puedes postear cuál sería el resultado que quieres en el caso de mismo número de visitas?

Comment: @Lamak;  La idea es que en caso de que un cliente tenga varias sucursales con el mismo número de visitas, seleccione cualquiera, indistintamente, pero que únicamente aparezca una cada cliente. Gracias.

Comment: @TOMZG ok, pero entonces la respuesta que está posteada te sirve perfectamente, no deberías tener el problema que pusiste en ese comentario

Answer (score 0):

**Lo que necesitas, hacer es lo siguiente:**

1.- Obtener la cantidad de veces que un cliente ha visitado a cada una de las sucursales.
La consulta quedaria mas o menos así:

```
SELECT Cliente, Sucursal, COUNT(*) Numero_Visitas
FROM ClienteSuc
GROUP BY cliente,sucursal
```

Y la consulta anterior te devolveria algo parecido a esto:

[image]
<sub>(fuente: [kn3.net](https://k62.kn3.net/2/B/5/A/1/F/0FF.png))</sub>

2.- La consulta anterior, lo meterás en una subconsulta dentro de un FROM y lo que harás es hacer una particion por cliente y ordenar por el campo Numero_Visitas de mayor a menor.
 Para ello nos auxiliaremos de la funcion ROW_NUMBER() y PARTITION BY.

La consulta quedaría algo asi:

```
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cliente ORDER BY Numero_Visitas DESC) AS Top_Visitas
    FROM (
          SELECT
          Cliente,
          Sucursal,
          COUNT(*) Numero_Visitas
        FROM ClienteSuc
        GROUP BY cliente,sucursal) SubconsultaInterna
```

Y eso te devolveria lo siguiente:

[image]
<sub>(fuente: [kn3.net](https://k62.kn3.net/D/6/A/7/8/4/360.png))</sub>

3.-Y por ultimo todo lo anterior tambien quedará dentro de una subconsulta, que será la que generé el resultado que tu quieres obtener, y esta consulta quedaria mas o menos asi.

```
SELECT
  Cliente,
  Sucursal
FROM (
    SELECT
    *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cliente ORDER BY Numero_Visitas DESC) AS Top_Visitas
    FROM (
          SELECT
          Cliente,
          Sucursal,
          COUNT(*) Numero_Visitas
        FROM ClienteSuc
        GROUP BY cliente,sucursal) SubconsultaInterna
    ) Subconsulta
WHERE Top_Visitas = 1
```

Y lo que devolveria finalmente es:

[image]
<sub>(fuente: [kn3.net](https://k62.kn3.net/1/9/7/D/0/8/CFC.png))</sub>

**Nota:***Se que puede parecer monstruoso el ROW_NUMBER() y el PARTITION BY, pero una vez que los entiendas te vas a enamorar de ellos, mas de alguna vez te sacarán de apuros en consultas que sean complejas.*
La documentacion de ellos puedes checarla aqui:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias; tienes razón; el ROW_NUMBER y el PARTITION_BY resultan inicialmente monstruosos, pero veo que tienen un gran poder de agrupación.  Lo que yo estaba haciendo es lo siguiente:  
;With cpd as(
Select cpd.Cliente, cpd.Sucursal, cpd.Prestamo,
 Rank()Over (Partition by Cliente order by Prestamo desc) as Rango
From dbo.Segmentacion           cpd
--Order by Cliente Desc
)
 Select

Comment: Este código me ha servido mucho, me estoy dando cuenta que el problema se presenta cuando un cliente tiene más de 1 visita a diferentes sucursales, es decir, a 3 sucursales, las visitó 2 veces, para el mismo cliente, me aparecerán las tres sucursales con el TOP 1, ¿Como podría seleccionar solamente 1 de las 3 sucursales indistintamente?

Comment: @TOMZG si usas `ROW_NUMBER` vas a obtener un resultado (incluso con repetición de número de visitas), así que debería ser lo que estás solicitando